# Perl SCP ERROR(Asking to Continue?)

Tags: perl, scp

Here's is what I am doing

```
my $username = "user";
my $password= "pass";
my $host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";

my $scpe =  Net::SCP::Expect->new(user => $username,
                                    password => $password,
                                    preserve => 1,
                                   recursive => 1,
                                  verbose=>1,
                  auto_yes=>1);

$scpe->scp("$file","$host:./drop/drop.txt");
```

When I run this code there is no error I am using unix box, `$file` is in my directory and have full permissions, also I have changed the directory to temp in unix box but when somebody else runs this code they get

> Problem performing scp: Are you sure
>   you want to continue connecting
>   (yes/no)?  at scp.pl line 242

I am very confused why is it happening, as this error is not received by me

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer:

Raise the `timeout_auto` value:

```
my $scpe =  Net::SCP::Expect->new(user => $username,
                                    password => $password,
                                    preserve => 1,
                                   recursive => 1,
                                  verbose=>1,
                                  timeout_auto=>10, #For example - 5 should probably be plenty
                  auto_yes=>1);
```

#### Long answer.

The

> problem performing scp

is what `Net::SCP::Expect` prepends to the literal error message it gets from SCP itself, so in this case

> Are you sure you want to continue
>   connecting (yes/no)?

This usually happens because the host SCP is connecting to is not yet known.

You should set `auto_yes` to 1 if you want to avoid this error [as the CPAN Documentation for NET::SCP::Expect explains](http://search.cpan.org/~djberg/Net-SCP-Expect-0.06/Expect.pm), but I see you're already doing that.

If that doesn't help, **consider raising the `timeout_auto` value**. It defaults to 1 second, but if it takes longer for SCP to pose the 'are you sure' question (because for example the DNS looking of the host takes longer), it might not be enough.